# Naming columns for high dimensional data in Python

Tags: python, bigdata, renaming

When I read in a .txt file python gives automatic names that are not very useful (i.e. 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3...). How do I rename all my columns without having to explicitly type it all?

For example, how do I quickly rename the variables V1 to V200?

Comment: How are you reading the text file?  How have you tried renaming them so far?  Are you using pandas or any third party libraries?

Comment: What code are you running that's giving names like "0.1"?

Comment: Pandas library - pd.read_table('location')
Python automatically gave it those names 0.1, 0.2, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
df.columns = ["feature_"+str(x) for x in range(len(df.columns))]
```